# Prevent user from checking items of listView .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm using a `listView` to display some test steps. During the test, if a step passes, I tick a corresponding `Item` on `listView` and change its `ForeColor` to green, if it fails I just change the `ForeColor` to red.

This `listView` is used only to display status of each test step.

Is there any way I can prevent user from clicking `Items` and changing the checked states?
One way to do it, would be to Disable the `listView`, but then the `ForeColor` can't be adjusted...

Comment: Just use the ListView.ItemCheck event, set the NewValue property to CurrentValue to cancel the change.  Plus a bool field in the form that you set to true to know that it was your code that checked the item.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Hans Passant, I now have the code below doing exactly what I was looking for:

```
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (allowCheck == false) //Set allowCheck to true, when your program needs to Check an item
    e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
}
```

Additionally I added following to cancel the highlighting when items are clicked:

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.Selected = false;
}
```